# Resume from Hibernate on Windows 7 takes a long time (suspect ReadyBoost)

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate, readyboost

Resuming from Hibernate on my Windows 7 desktop takes an awefully long time, I'd guess 5 minutes. It is an Intel DP35DP with 64 bit Intel Core2 Duo E6750, 2GB and 2x320GB RAID0.

Sony Lin's blog post [Fixing Windows 7 can't return from stand by (sleep) or hibernate when Readyboost is used](http://www.sonylin.net/Computers/windows_7_standby.php) points to the problem. It would seem that Windows 7 has to recreate the ReadyBoost cache, possibly at low speed, before it is able to come back up. Removing my ReadyBoost setup (Lexar Jump Drive Lightning II 120x 18MB/s 2GB USB key) eliminates the long resume issue.

Challenge is that I'd like to use ReadyBoost, without having to wait for my system when it resumes? Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 2):

The problem may also be that your hard disk and the ReadyBoost is has different formats (e.g. HD is NTFS and the USB/Flash Fat32). Reformat (the latter).

See: [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/black-screen-after-hibernation-with-readyboost-sd/1d679969-7888-47c5-b748-6ddebcc2ad76)

A rather late answer ,-) but other may pop in via Google and find it useful.

Comment: Amazing that this isn't prominent in the help or suggested via the Action Center. Thank you!

Comment: Afraid this seems to have lessened the occurence, but hasn't resolved ,the problem. Purposefully putting the PC into sleep mode and then resuming is quick, but if the machine hibernates on its own, then the lengthy resume reoccurs. Still a useful tip that I hadn't seen anywhere else. I've now given up on Readyboost for good.

Answer (score 1):

Okay this answer is a work in progress, but my solution would be to disable readyboost just before hibernate and re-enable just after hibernate resume.  So we use task scheduler with triggers to launch the script like so:

1. Open Task Scheduler [Start> Control Panel> System and Maintenance> Administrative Tools> Task Scheduler (or just type "task Scheduler" into the Start Search box)]. You will need an Administrator's Account/Password to access this.
2. Select "Create a Task" to create a new task.
3. A panel with several tabs will open.
4. Fill the "General" tab to suit your needs.
5. Switch to the "Triggers" tab and choose "new". Another Panel will open. At the top of this Panel, you will see a drop-down menu (see below). Open it and choose "At Workstation Unlock". Then choose whether you would like this task to run just for your profile or for everyone's. Click "ok". (You may find it useful to use the "Delay task for" option to delay the task for 15/30 seconds to give your desktop a chance to load before the program runs.)

Switch to the Actions tab, select "new", choose "Run a Program", and browse to the program you wish to run.

7. Switch to the "Conditions" & "Settings" tabs, respectively, and change the various settings to suit your needs. (Make sure that the "Run on AC Only" option is unchecked if you are using a laptop and want the task to run when it is unplugged.)
8. Click ok to save your new task.

from here: http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistaappearance/thread/72150ea7-22f2-4043-93b0-aad517c28fc0

on lock and on unlock are probably the trigger events you need

## To start a service:

```
*

  Net start name_of_service
```

## To stop a service:

```
*

  Net stop name_of_service
```

Service Name (registry): EMDMgmt
haven't tested it, but it should make resume faster, going to hibernate might still be slow

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Is a little more complicated than I was anticipating. Are "On lock" and "On unlock" the right triggers (I allow the system to determine standby, sleep & hibernate after periods of inactivity)?

Comment: lock and unlock should happen for all three

Answer (score 0):

Formatting the USB as exFAT [could solve the problem](http://www.sonylin.net/Computers/windows_7_standby.php).

Comment: How does it solve the problem?